# Number of vowels, consonants and syllables in a text document with Rapidminer

Tags: text-mining, rapidminer

I have a very short question: how to calculate the number of vowels, consonants and syllables in a text document with RapidMiner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace vowels with blank and calculate lengths before and after. Same for consonants. Syllables more challenging.

Comment: Thank you for you help. It works fine with vowels and consonants. Do you know how to do the same for syllables?

Comment: You would need some external data that maps words to syllables and replace words with the mapping